# Как поставить бесконечное прослушивание событий используя модуль event

Tags: node.js, события

Есть код

```
const telegram_bot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const color = require('colors');
const EventEmitter = require('events')


const now = new Date()
const settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./keys.json'))
const bot = new telegram_bot(settings.token, {polling: true });


const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();



myEmitter.on('update', async (time) => { 
  const mes = () => new Promise(res => {
    bot.on('message', msg =>{
      res(msg.text);
    })
  }) 

  const jun = async (elem) =>{
    if(elem < 15){
      console.log('Меньше 15')
    }
    if(elem < 45 && elem > 15){
      console.log('В промежутке')
    }
    if(elem > 45 ){
      console.log('Больше всего')
    }
  }
  jun(await mes())
  
});


myEmitter.emit('update')


console.log(color.green('Бот запущен'))
```

Сейчас он выключается после того как событие выполнилось 1 раз, как поставить, чтобы событие прослушивалось бесконечное количество раз?